# Preview Images Inside Folder Icons

Tags: macos, finder, folders, icon

Can I insert an image or more than one image into a folder icon, (like overlaying the image onto the folder icon itself) so I can see some of the data that is in that folder before I click on it? I think I did this with Windows years ago and not sure which OS it was but can I do this in El Capitan and Yosemite?

Answer (score 0):

If you have write privileges on the folder, you can do this:

1. open the parent folder in Finder, in icon view
2. change the icon size to as large as possible.
3. Take a screen shot of the folder icon and paste into a graphics editor.
4. Add whatever you want to the image.
5. In Finder, select the folder you want to change.
6. Cmd-I or Get Info
7. Select the image you have edited (or any other image).  Copy only the image without background.  If you can't do that, make the background transparent and the image dimensions equal (square).
8. Cmd-C (Copy) to put the image in the clipboard.
9. Click on the folder icon in the upper left of the Get Info window.
10. Ctrl-V (paste) to replace the icon from the clipboard.